# Error in image panel class of java : error:image panel cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, image, panel

How to use image panel class, here it is showing error: `image panel cannot be   resolved to a type`! How to create an image panel class object?

```
public void start() 
{ 
   ImagePanel im=new ImagePanel("C:/om1.jpg");//ERROR:image panel cannot be       resolved to a type 
   add(im); 
   setSize(400,400); 
   setVisible(true); 
   addMouseListener(this); 
   addMouseMotionListener( this ); 
   setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Comment: import `ImagePanel`...

Comment: what is `ImagePanel`? Where is it located, which package?

Comment: Can you please show us the rest of the code, say the ImagePanel class for instance? Thanks

Comment: i have already imported image panel!!